# How can I use react-native-pdf module at the expo project?

Tags: expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Azxg.png)
I'm going to make the pdf viewer that can use in expo.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use react-native-pdf in expo as it require native modules.

However there are several ways to read PDF's in expo, for example you could simply use a webview or you could use a different JS only library for example
https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js

If you really want to use expo and native modules (and therefore react-native-pdf) you could move from managed workflow to bare workflow see below for more details

https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/